# Moving the back ground screen as well as maintaning the tragetory path of a ball in Iphone Game apps

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have game application (cocos2d) in which, a ball is to be shooted from a cannon, this ball travels through a trajectory path and land on a building. Now the problem is that according to the requirement I have to increase the size of the background image due to which my building image is not visible on first view and with the ball traveling i have to drag the background image with out disturbing the trajectory path of the ball. Can some one help me out in this regards. To clarify question bit more I am also attaching a image. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you have are two different coordinate spaces that should be independent from each other.
The ball should move in the "world" coordinate space, independently from the "screen" coordinate space. Of course that the "world" must be displayed on the "screen", so you must convert the "world" coordinate space to "screen" coordinate space, which in you case is a simple translation that can be done by adding an offset.

On iPhone, you can simply put all the "world objects" inside a `UIView` and move that 'UIView' left and right, while the world objects move relatively to the "world" inside that view, and the conversion from "world coordinate space" (the view coordinate space) to the screen coordinate space will be done for you when the view is drawn on screen.

Comment: am not clear about this. can you explain breifly.  i do not understand what is the coordinate space. here am not using uiview this is an cocos2d game application.

Comment: I mean you have two coordinate systems. Two origins of coordinates that should be independent. The position of the ball should always be relative to the "world" origin. The position of the "world" can be moved relative to the "screen" origin.

Answer (score 3):

In cocos2d the easiest way to accomplish this is to move your entire layer.  If you're doing things in the normal cocos2d way, you have a class that subclasses CCLayer.

Within that class you can simply change its position and you'll get the desired effect.

In your example, since you want to move the "camera" to the right, you can simply move the layer to the left.  for example:

```
-(void) centerOnBuilding {
    CGPoint distanceToMove = ccp(-120, 0);
    self.position = ccpAdd(distanceToMove, self.position);
}
```

That function, in a CCLayer, will have the effect of centering the camera 120 pixels to the right of where it was before.  If you want to have a scrolling effect, do the same thing but run a MoveTo or MoveBy action in the layer.